# Как заменить кнопку на картинку любой формы?

Tags: html, css

Нужно на кнопку назначить картинку свою, делаю так:

Html

```
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Css:

```
.button{
    background: url('../images/red/top.png'); 
}
```

Но кнопка получается стандартной формы, и картинка в ней просто размножается, и надпись "Кнопка" видна, если надпись убираю, то она становится очень маленькой, и картинки нет. А мне надо, чтобы кнопка была той формы, какой я сделаю картинку, и надпись мне не надо, написать я хочу на самой картинке. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
button 
{
    background: url(../img/button_img.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно... Размеры ширины и высоты указывайте любые.

Comment: .button{
      background: url('../images/red/top.png') no-repeat; 
      width: 35px;
      height: 30px;

Сделал так,указал размеры картинки, картинку видно но она будто в квадратной кнопке,а мне нужно что бы было видно только картинку,а картинка у меня своеобразной формы.Если делаю по вашему способу то кнопка опять становится маленькой и без картинки.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы контуров кнопки не было видно, а то получается как картинка в квадратной кнопке, а мне нужно, чтобы отображалась только картинка без кнопки.

Comment: border: none; 
решит вашу проблему

Comment: Да,вот то что нужно,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить стили для кнопки.

```
<style>
.button{
        background: none;
        border: none;
    } 
</style>
<button class="button" name="leaf" value="1"><img src="img/ico/right.png"></button>
```

Если размер картинки не задан при её сохранении, то нжуно прописать в стиле. Например:

```
width="70px" height="40px";
```

так я вставляю рисунки с прозрачным слоем, которые сами являются кнопками.